# log scale x-axis labels

Tags: r

The labels on the x-axis are defaulting to scientific notation no matter how small cex.axis is.  How can I override scientific notation to get the labels to print out as specified?  Here is the code (UNIT here is 0.0105):

```
plot( xm,yv ,log="xy",ylim=c(0.1,20)/UNIT,
  xlim=c(0.004,20)*UNIT,xlab="Dose",xaxt="n",ylab="Amount",type="n")
axis(1,at=c(0.0001,0.005,0.001,0.05,0.01,0.5,1),cex.axis=0.9)
```

Answer (score 4):

try using the `labels=` argument in `axis()` and providing an `as.character()` version of your `at=` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set `options(scipen=5)` before your plot. `scipen=0` is the default on my system, so you could try integers >0 to see which one gives you the results you are looking for.